# For Loop gives Object Required Error

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am comparatively new to UFT as well as VB script.
I am trying to check innertext of divs inside For loop.

```
set getData = Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Object.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")
'Below line outputs 5'
msgbox getData.length-1
'output innertext for all these divs'
For i=0 to getData.length-1
       msgbox getData(i).innertext  
Next
```

This gives me Object Required Error on this line

```
msgbox getData(i).innertext
```

My first and 2nd element is blank while 3,4,5 are non-empty values.
When I write

```
msgbox getData(0).innertext
msgbox getData(1).innertext
msgbox getData(2).innertext
```

It gives me proper results

I further need to check this data against "Data" spreadsheet in UFT
Any pointers would be very much helpful.
Thanks,

Comment: `For Each thing in collection` is a way of looping through a array or collection. `thing` (which you can call anything, `obj` perhaps) is the contents of the array or a object if a collection.

Comment: I also tried -- 

    For Each myData in getData 
    msgbox myData.innertext

.. that doesn't work either. It says, Objct doesn't support this property or method at For Each line

Comment: Therefore find out what you have. On your data do a `VarType` and IsEmpty etc on your thing.

Comment: Can you add related html fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clarification needed:**

As you would like to query div text, Is that any reason to use ClassName? If that so, you could use getElementsbyTagName instead getElementsByClassName.

However, I enhanced the code and adapting the query by any tag name option in the function. Here you go.

```
Dim objResultsDictionary

Set objResultsDictionary = GetTextContentFromHtmlTag(Browser("title:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").Page("title:=.*"),"div","")
Msgbox objResultsDictionary.Count

Result:8

Set objResultsDictionary = GetTextContentFromHtmlTag(Browser("title:=Welcome: Mercury Tours").Page("title:=.*"),"ClassName","mouseOut")
Msgbox objResultsDictionary.Count

Result = 11

Public Function GetTextContentFromHtmlTag(ByVal BrowserObject,ByVal TagName,ByVal TagValue)
    Dim objDictionary
    Dim objCollection
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Select Case UCase(TagName)
        Case "DIV"
            Set objCollection = BrowserObject.Object.getElementsByTagName(TagName)
        Case "CLASSNAME"
            Set objCollection = BrowserObject.Object.getElementsByClassName(TagValue)
    End Select
    intDivCount = objCollection.Length
    If intDivCount > 0 Then
        For intCounter = 0 To intDivCount
            If IsObject(objCollection(intCounter)) Then
                strTagInnerText = objCollection(intCounter).innerText
                If strTagInnerText <> "" Then
                    objDictionary.Add intCounter,strTagInnerText
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Set GetTextContentFromHtmlTag = objDictionary
End Function
```

**What you have to do:**

You have to iterate the dictionary and get the innertext of the each tag.

Comment: I am going to try it out, looks like it's gonna work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Its giving you that error most probably because, there is various elements with the same class name other than the div or divs.
Try using some other properties.